# Perché la presenza di "non" in questa frase?

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood

Qualche settimana fa ho provato a tradurre una frase che mi sembrava abbastanza complicata;

> It would have taken him longer than he had been alive.

La traduzione era

> Ci sarebbe voluto più tempo di quanto non fosse stato vivo.

Si vede che, nella frase italiana, si usa "non" davanti al congiuntivo imperfetto, ma nella sua controparte inglese, non c'è.

Il problema è che non capisco qual è la regola grammaticale che giustifica la presenza di "non" in questa frase. Immagino che sia la presenza del congiuntivo imperfetto che spiega il fenomeno. Esiste un principio generale che spiega quando usare "non" in una frase del genere?

Comment: Da dove trai la versione italiana (“Ci sarebbe voluto più tempo di quanto non fosse stato vivo”)? Francamente la trovo un po' goffa e anche non chiarissima. Ho dovuto guardare l'originale inglese, per essere sicuro di capire che cosa si intendeva. Non la prenderei come modello per imparare l'uso del condizionale (o altro). Io avrei detto “Ci avrebbe messo un tempo più lungo di tutta la sua vita fino ad allora”, o qualcosa del genere: bisogna vedere qual è il contesto.

Comment: Il non pleonastico può comparire anche in due tipi di proposizioni secondarie al congiuntivo, quasi a sottolinearne il significato in qualche modo irreale. 1) proposizione comparativa

*”Mia figlia ritorna a casa prima di quanto (non) abbiamo creduto possibile*”  e 2) la proposizione eccettuativa solitamente introdotta da “a meno che”: 

“*Vado a dormire a meno che mia figlia (non) rientri in casa.*”

Comment: @DaG la frase italiana viene da Google Traduttore. Mi piace la tua revisione della frase, grazie.

Comment: @Hachi Interessante. Quindi anche il "non" nella frase originale è facoltativo?

Comment: @Asa_D - si è pleonastico. Ma concordo che la frase sia poco chiara.

Comment: OP, posso suggerire, se ti interessa il “non” pleonastico, di inserire nella domanda una vera frase italiana al posto di quella generata da Google Translate, che suona un po' aliena?